# The filter generate by keras Convolution2D

Tags: keras, convolution

I have a question about the function 'Convolution2D' in keras.

```
model.add(Convolution2D(
    nb_filter=32,
    nb_row=5,
    nb_col=5,
    border_mode='same',
    input_shape=(1,28,28),
))
```

By doing this, 32 5*5 filters will be used to convolute the input. But only size of the filters is specified, what does these filters look like? Are they all the same or random numbers in each one?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one filter that is convolved over the layer input.
The filter is initialized using the `kernel_initializer` which is `glorot_uniform`
by default.

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/initializers/) on `glorot_uniform`:

- It draws samples from a uniform distribution within `[-limit, limit]` where limit is `sqrt(6 / (fan_in + fan_out))` where `fan_in` is the number of input units in the weight tensor and `fan_out` is the number of output units in the weight tensor

Note that the filter changes during the training of the layer. It is optimized to recognize features that help your model make a correct classification.
I found a good explanation [here](https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/).

Comment: if all the 32 filters are the same, aren't the convolution results the same?

Comment: No, because the filter is multiplied with the pixels of the image. Unless your image has the same pixel values everywhere, the convolution results will be different.
sidenote: I assume you are working with images, 2D data does not necessarily need to be of an image.